# How to remove object-item from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

[image]

How can I delete event(object) from my events(object). It seems to be pretty simple but I'm kinda stuck trying to figure it out for like an hour

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Let's say I want this events list but without the 3rd object

Comment: `yourArray.splice(3, 1)`

Comment: It's not clear how this image relates to the question.  Are you asking how to remove a property from an object?  How to remove an element from an array?  Something else?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates what you're trying and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const events = events.filter(ev => ev.title !== 'TEST ZDJEC');
```

This will remove 3rd one, since in filter you are specifying that you want to keep only elements with title different than 'TEST ZDJEC';